# layout with text surrounding a button

Tags: android, android-layout

could some one suggest me how to implement the layout like following:

[image]

That's multiple lines of texts surrounding a button. Probably a linear layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `two linear layouts`

```
inner layout with horizontal orientation ( which will one textview and one button)
outer layout with verticalr orientation which wil have textview with wrap content
```

Similar to the following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Clear Cache"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this mean he will have to split the text into theese seperate textViews?

Comment: well that isn't really a solution to this, just a workaround. what this means is that you will have to know where to split the text so it looks natural, which means measuring how many characters it can hold or something similar right?

Comment: I agree with @DArkO. This is just a workaround. What if the content of the text is dynamic, an extra function needed to decide where to split the text then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout and then the you can format the layout with the command

```
android:layout_above="@+id/mybutton"

android:layout_below="@+id/mybutton"

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mybutton"

android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mybutton"
```

See more infos to RelativeLayout at the API-Site (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

So have only one Layout with 5 componentes (4 TextFileds and the Button)

EDIT:

here is a quick and dirty solution - but it worked fine for me

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_above"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/my_button"
        android:text="TEXT ABOVE BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/my_button"
        android:text="TEXT LEFT OF BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_button"
        android:text="TEXT RIGHT OF BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_BELOW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_button"
        android:text="TEXT BELOW BUTTON"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />      
    </RelativeLayout>
```